# Viewing man pages through CLion on Windows' Documentation Viewer

Tags: clion, manpage

CLion on Linux shows the corresponding man page when viewing the documentation for a C library function or a system call. I have both man and man pages installed locally on Windows and in the Windows Subsystem for Linux. Is there a way to point CLion to either of the locations where those pages and man are installed, so that it will use them when viewing documentation from within CLion?

Answer (score 0):

I test and find that it can work on Windows. As long as you can execute `man` on cmd.

The simplest way is to install cygwin or msys2 on Windows and then install man-db on environment.
After that add the executable file path to system path environment.
Make sure you can call `man printf` on cmd.

I find out that Clion will detect the toolchain and then decide whether execute `man` or not.
If your toolchain is mingw other than cygwin or wsl, Clion won't show the man page.
But the stupid thing is, Clion will only execute `man` on Windows system, it's not the correct way it suppose.
**Clion SHOULD execute `man` on toolchain environment.**

There is already an issue on youtrack right now.
Here is the link https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-23332.